# Java null exception

Tags: java, mysql

This is the design view where it got problem retrieving back

```
    Volunteer volunteer = Volunteer.Volunteer();

    tf_fName = new JTextField();
    tf_fName.setBounds(300, 113, 159, 20);
    add(tf_fName);
    tf_fName.setColumns(10);
    tf_fName.setText(volunteer.getFirstName());
```

This is the error received. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at volunteer.ui.VolunteerView$1.actionPerformed(VolunteerView.java:57)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

This is the entity class.

```
public static Volunteer Volunteer(){


    Volunteer users = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery;

   //Step 1 -connect to database
    db.getConnection();

    //step 2 - declare the SQL statement
    dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM volunteer";
```

This part is retrieving back the information.

```
  // step 3 - using DBController, use updateRequest method 
        rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
        try{
              while (rs.next()){
                int ID = rs.getInt("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
                String sex = rs.getString("sex");
                String language = rs.getString("language"); 
                String dob = rs.getString("dob");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                String address2 = rs.getString("address2");

               users  = new Volunteer(ID, firstName, lastName, sex, language, dob, address,     address2);   

           }
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // step 4 - close connection 
        db.terminate();
        return users;
    }
```

UPDATE : This is the constructor

```
public Volunteer(String firstName, String lastName, String sex, String language, String dob, String address, String address2) { 
super();
this.firstName = firstName; 
this.lastName = lastName; 
this.sex = sex; 
this.language = language; 
this.dob = dob; 
this.address = address; 
this.address2 = address2; }
```

Line 57 points to

```
JPanel contentPane = new Profile(myFrame);
            myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll(); //this is line 57
            myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Update 2  :This is the place where i initizated myFrame

```
        public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static Users myExp = null;
    private static JFrame myFrame = null;
    private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                myFrame = frame;
                JPanel contentPane = new Login(myFrame);
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Which line is `VolunteerView.java:57`?

Comment: Can you post the contructor for Volunteer?

Comment: Is the second capital V in this line a typo? `public static Volunteer Volunteer(){`.

Comment: "error ...What can I do to prevent this from happening?" -> Catch it ;)

Comment: The volunteer returned by the Volunteer() method is null if the try-catch failed, that could be the problem. Also seconding Andreas question.

Comment: @JuanManuel public Volunteer(String firstName, String lastName, String sex,
   String language, String dob, String address, String address2) {
  super();
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.sex = sex;
  this.language = language;
  this.dob = dob;
  this.address = address;
  this.address2 = address2;
 }

Comment: @Andreas      myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();

Comment: Do not dump code in comments. Put them neatly in the question.

Comment: Another thing by the look of it, users should be an Array or Vector. But it's not defined that way

Comment: @OP Please point out which line is `VolunteerView.java:57`

Comment: @ADTC OP didn't post that line

Comment: @Andreas Added in already, its link into a another page

Comment: @JuanManuel i did try with arraylist and it have the same error

Comment: I didn't mean that the lack of the array is the solution, is another problem, the way it is only returns the last Volunteer in the table.

Comment: Where do you initialize the myFrame object?

Comment: @JuanManuel i have added in on the top post

Comment: There's something missing between the assignation of contentPane to new Login(), and contentPane = new Profile(), why you set the Frame visible again?

Comment: @JuanManuel Frame visible so that the another page can use it? Pardon me, i just started learning programming.